# installation of Ros kinetic in Mac Mojave

Tags: installation, ros, macos-mojave

I'm tring to install ros kinetic in my mac following this [guide](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source).
(I have homebrew installed and updated) In the first step of the guide I run the command line:

```
brew tap ros/deps
```

and this get me back the following errors

```
    ==> Tapping ros/deps
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/ros/homebrew-deps'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 11, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (11/11), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
remote: Total 11 (delta 0), reused 4 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/ros/homebrew-deps/gfortran.rb
Calling MacOS.prefer_64_bit? is disabled! There is no replacement.
Please report this to the ros/deps tap:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/ros/homebrew-deps/gfortran.rb:15

Error: Cannot tap ros/deps: invalid syntax in tap!
```

this is my `brew --config`

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 2.0.3-28-gd8c6f6b
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: d8c6f6b12075a06a9837f6fce920ccd07a36ca4c
Last commit: 21 minutes ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 7be50eb2d1dbe7aa885ce349279f71baadca87c6
Core tap last commit: 17 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_DEV_CMD_RUN: 1
HOMEBREW_DISPLAY: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.uz5VqgRPje/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
HOMEBREW_LOGS: /Users/giuliopettenuzzo/Library/Logs/Homebrew
CPU: quad-core 64-bit broadwell
Homebrew Ruby: 2.3.7 => /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.7/bin/ruby
Clang: 9.0 build 900
Git: 2.14.3 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: 1.8.0_131
macOS: 10.14.2-x86_64
CLT: N/A
Xcode: 9.2
XQuartz: 2.7.11 => /opt/X11
```

and this is the errors I get with `brew doctor`

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  python@2
  numpy

Warning: Your Xcode (9.2) is too outdated.
Please update to Xcode 10.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.


Warning: Your Xcode (9.2) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 10.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.
```

This error avoid me to install ross kinetic in my mac mojave, please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/ros/homebrew-deps

I put this repository into /⁨usr/⁨local/⁨Homebrew/⁨Library/⁨Taps/⁨ros/⁩homebrew-dep,
then in gfortran.rb, modify "MacOS.prefer_64_bit" to "MacOS.is_64_bit".
and run "brew tap ros/deps" again.

It works on my Mac.

Comment: thanks.. this seems to be the solution for my answer! did you manage to install ros kinetik kame in your mac?

Comment: Could you explain more details where should I put the git repository in? Is it `/⁨usr/⁨local/⁨Homebrew/⁨Library/⁨Taps/⁨ros/<git repo homebrew-deps>` or `/⁨usr/⁨local/⁨Homebrew/⁨Library/⁨Taps/⁨ros/homebrew-dep/<git repo homebrew-deps>`? Thanks you!!

Comment: Create the directory using `mkdir /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/ros`. Change to that directory using `cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/ros`. Finally clone the repository with `git clone https://github.com/ros/homebrew-deps`.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly for `weaveworks/tap` to install eksctl in Mac  :

```
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/weaveworks/homebrew-tap/Formula/eksctl-private.rb eksctl-private: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/weaveworks/homebrew-tap/Formula/eksctl-private.rb:15: unknown regexp options - gthb Error: Cannot tap weaveworks/tap: invalid syntax in tap!
```

To fix it follow this :

1. `cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/`
2. `mkdir homebrew-tap/`
3. `git clone https://github.com/weaveworks/homebrew-tap.git`
4. `brew tap weaveworks/tap`
5. `brew install weaveworks/tap/eksctl`